# Light up screen when notification received android

Tags: android, notifications, screen, wakelock, wakeup

I have a service running for my application to send notification every hour. This is working fine as i heard a sound and a vibration every hour because of my notification but i also want that my notification light up my screen as well. But i am unable to light up my screen when notification appears.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
boolean isScreenOn = pm.isScreenOn();
Log.e("screen on........", ""+isScreenOn);
if(isScreenOn==false)
{
    WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK |PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP |PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE,"myApp:MyLock");
    wl.acquire(10000);
    WakeLock wl_cpu = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,"myApp:mycpuMyCpuLock");

    wl_cpu.acquire(10000);
}
```

Comment: FULL_WAKE_LOCK is deprecated now. What use instead?

Comment: I have the same question as Orium.

Comment: you need WakeLock permission in manifest: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

Comment: isScreenOn() was deprecated in API level 20. Use isInteractive() instead.

Comment: Thanks. You solved my issue for wake up lock. Now my app properly wake up for notifications.

Comment: FULL_WAKE_LOCK is deprecated. Use PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK instead.

Comment: @KaiWang Are we supposed to use PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK on both wl and wl_cpu instances?

Comment: @SametSahin I'm not sure about it. Sorry dude :)

Comment: `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK` will not wake up a device on its own, and [the Android docs state](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager#ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP) it cannot be used with `ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP`

Comment: will this code come after notification code in broadcastreceiver?

Answer (score 6):

Here is my solution:

```
createNotification(); //your implementation
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
boolean isScreenOn = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 20 ? pm.isInteractive() : pm.isScreenOn(); // check if screen is on
if (!isScreenOn) {
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "myApp:notificationLock");
    wl.acquire(3000); //set your time in milliseconds
}
```

More at [PowerManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager)

Comment: Do i need to release wakelock like ```wl.release()```  ?