# Android : Battery drains around 4 hours common with wifi ON and screen ON always

Tags: android, android-wifi

My app is single activity app which is used to generate token slip using WiFi printer over wifi which are connected locally. So the WiFi is always ON. Also the screen is always ON.

I have set `android:keepScreenOn="true"` in my activity xml file for this.

The tablet is exclusively used for this single app only not more than that. Even though, the battery drains around 4 hours.

Is this common? Or Would I change anything to achieve good battery backup?

Comment: How could we know if we don't know what is the specs of your phone, as well as how is your App logic?

Comment: 4 hours of screen on time sounds like it's about right.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/index.html

Comment: @Raptor , sorry for inconvenience. I am using Fusion5 106 (10.6 inch, 8GB, Wi-Fi Only) tablet. Please see the complete details in this link. [link](http://www.amazon.in/Fusion5-106-Tablet-Wi-Fi-White/dp/B0100O2ESQ)

Comment: You should either connect to power, or don't use `keepScreenOn`.

Comment: @Falmarri. Is there anyway to increase the battery stands around 7 hours with above mentioned case?

Comment: @Raptor, In our app, Owner has to generate token continuously based on customer visit. If i remove 'keepScreenOn', they have to click on power button for wake up the screen. it doesn't make them feeling good.

Comment: You can make use of Notifications.

Comment: @Raptor, Sorry. I couldn't understand. How could I use Notifications here? Would you please explain little more?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9631869/light-up-screen-when-notification-received-android)

Comment: @Raptor, The post used to light up the screen, when notification comes. But In my case, there is no notification. It is like generating token for coffee at coffee shop. How could I use notification logic here?

Comment: In my imagination, the notification content can be *You have received a token*. Once access the notification, the App will open with the token displayed.

Comment: @Raptor, Ok. Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Generally if your device is old, There is a chance to expect this kind of situation.

To debug about your network traffic, Follow this link

> The network traffic generated by an app can have a significant impact
>   on the battery life of the device where it is running. In order to
>   optimize that traffic, you need to both measure it and identify its
>   source. Network requests can come directly from a user action,
>   requests from your own app code, or from a server communicating with
>   your app.

Link is [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/power/network/gather-data.html)

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will test and update the result. FYI, App doesn't connect with remote server, network intensive task,any external request etc. It is purely used to print the string to thermal printer over WiFi, **locally**