# How to wake up locked screen after notification popup in API level 28?

Tags: android, android-notifications, lockscreen

I have a problem with a lock screen light when I want to do wake up a light of lock screen when the local notification pops up on a device. 
How can I do this? 
Please help me on this topic on recent android Nougat and Oreo

Comment: what does it have to do with java?

Answer (score 1):

That has been already answered here: [How to make a screen wake up when a notification is received?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45415774/how-to-make-a-screen-wake-up-when-a-notification-is-received)

here: [Light up screen when notification received android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9631869/light-up-screen-when-notification-received-android)

and here: [Turning on screen programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891337/turning-on-screen-programmatically)

You can choose, which approach fits your purpose best.