# Android : Screen is not waking up

Tags: android, wakelock

I am working on calling feature and i want an activity to be opened and the screen to wake up whenever there is an incoming call. I am able to start the activity but am not able to wake up the screen. I have tried as many solutions available here on Stackoverflow, still no luck.

I am providing the links of few of the solutions i have tried..

[Turning on screen programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891337/turning-on-screen-programmatically)

[Light up screen when notification received android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9631869/light-up-screen-when-notification-received-android)

Can anyone help me out with how can I achieve this?

Comment: show your code here

Comment: PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
                    PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP
                            | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "MyWakeLock");
                    wakeLock.acquire();

Comment: and whats your Android OS version in the device your are testing on ?

Comment: I am testing it on Android 5 and newer

Comment: it would be good if you also post the logcat message.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to activity you want to open when screen is locked:

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    Window window = getWindow();
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please provide a bit more information (or post the screen activity fragment ideally) from what i understand reading the 2 solutions you included 
you have not set the flags at all for the windowmanager :

```
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

the full wake lock method is deprecated and it is likely to kill the activity